# Determine applied rules when using a classifier for prediction in Weka

Tags: classification, weka, prediction

I can build a classification model in Weka (JRip, J48, etc.) and run it to predict classes for a test set.

Is there a way to explain each prediction instance (either in Explorer or via coding)? In other words, I need to determine which rule/tree branch has been employed to predict the class for each instance in my test set.

Comment: After you have built the model in Explorer, you can right-click on it and "Visualize tree". This does not answer your question, but is more than nothing. Have you tried this?

Comment: I've tried the visualization. But it doesn't seem to offer any more information than the textual representation in the output.